# can't declare method in class (c++_

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

In my header file I declare structure

```
    typedef struct _PreprocessedImage
{
  cv::Rect straight;
  cv::Rect diagonal;
  bool empty = true;
...
...
} PreprocessedImage;
```

Then I create class with method

```
std::vector<float> processData(cv::Mat &image, bool drawRegions = false, PreprocessedImage &preproc);
.
```

Try to compile and got

> "error: default argument missing for parameter 3"

But when I try to declare method with default value, like that:

```
 std::vector<float> processData(cv::Mat &image, bool drawRegions = false, PreprocessedImage &preproc = PreprocessedImage());
.
```

I got

> "error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type
>   'PreprocessedImage& {aka _PreprocessedImage&}' from an rvalue of type
>   'PreprocessedImage {aka _PreprocessedImage}'"

How can i fix it?

Comment: Parameters with default values must appear all at the end of the parameter list.

Comment: don't `typedef struct ... name` in `C++`. Just do `struct name`

Comment: Unrelated: Identifiers beginning with an underscore followed by a capital letter are implementation-reserved and you are not allowed to use them in your code.

Answer (score 1):

All parameters with defaults should be at the *end* of the list, so you need something like:

```
std::vector<float> processData(cv::Mat &image, PreprocessedImage &preproc, bool drawRegions = false);
.
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to paxdiablo's answer.

Yes, the default-argument parameters must come last. Your attempt to work around this by also giving `preproc` a default argument failed because a temporary cannot bind to an lvalue reference (it would have to be `const`); besides, giving something a default "for the sake of it" is probably not what you wanted to do.

An alternative, that doesn't require re-arranging your existing function, is to write a forwarding overload instead of using default arguments:

```
std::vector<float> processData(cv::Mat& image, bool drawRegions, PreprocessedImage& preproc)
{
   /* ... */
}

std::vector<float> processData(cv::Mat& image, PreprocessedImage& preproc)
{
   return processData(image, false, preproc);
}
```

By the way, you don't need (or want) that antique C-style `typedef struct A { ... } B` syntax in C++ (unless you require direct C compatibility); you just want `struct B`. And, if you really must go for the former, you should pick a name that isn't [reserved to the implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/560648).